# Using a Vector to fill up array of Class object - DMX Fixture Profile

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct

Im writing a program to control different lights with DMX protocol. Each light has different channels to control different aspects (like Intensity, Color Temperature, colors etc.)

For that i want to create an easy way to put together a profile for each light.

This is what I came up so far. I'm working with an Arduino Due.

When I print out values after initialization, it just prints out `0` . Could somebody help me explain, what im doing wrong here? Or is there a better way to do this?

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct Channel {
  String name;
  String unit;
  int minValue;
  int maxValue;
  int color;
  int dmxChannels;
  int sliderChannels;  

}; Channel AladdinBiColor[2], AladdinRGB[6];

class Profile {
  public:
  std::vector<Channel> channels;
  int dmxChannels;
  int sliderChannels;
  String name[];
  String unit[];
  int minValue[];
  int maxValue[];
  int color[];

  Profile(Channel* input, int count){
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
      channels.push_back(*input);
      input++;
    }
  }
};

Profile AladdinBiColor_fixture(AladdinBiColor, 2);
Profile AladdinRGB_fixture(AladdinRGB, 6);
```

in Setup I call this function:

```cpp
void setup(){

   void initializeProfiles();
   Serial.println(AladdinBiColor_fixture.channels[0].maxValue);
}
```

this prints out `0`

which looks like this. It initializes the array.

```cpp
void initializeProfiles(){
  AladdinBiColor[0] = {"INT","%", 0, 100, WHITE,2,2};
  AladdinBiColor[1] = {"INT","%", 0, 100, WHITE,2,2};

  AladdinRGB[0] = {"INT","%", 0, 100, WHITE,2,2};
  AladdinRGB[1] = {"INT","%", 0, 100, WHITE,2,2};
  AladdinRGB[2] = {"CF","%", 0, 100, WHITE,2,2};
  AladdinRGB[3] = {"RED","%", 0, 100, RED,2,2};
  AladdinRGB[4] = {"GREEN","%", 0, 100, GREEN,2,2};
  AladdinRGB[5] = {"BLUE","%", 0, 100, BLUE,2,2};
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]. In the code you posted there is no printing of values after intitialization that could show a 0

Comment: `String name[];` and all the other members with unspecified array size is non standard C++. You are already using `std::vector`, why not also for those member? (though it looks like they are just repeating what is already stored in the vector of `Channels` and I suppose thats part of the confusion in the code you do not show)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number im really new to programming, also with vectors. Is there a better way to achieve this? This is basically the hole code to deal with the profile. Or how can I use vector also for those members. like putting into the unspecified array `[sizeof(channels)]`

Answer (score 1):

So the Problem was that the initialization took place after the Profile objects have been created. I rearranged the order and created an array which points to the objects of `Profile` so one can access it easily.

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct Channel {
  String name;
  String unit;
  int minValue;
  int maxValue;
  int color;
}; 

Channel AladdinBiColor[2] = {
  {"INT","%", 0, 100, WHITE},
  {"CCT","K", 0, 100, WHITE}
};

Channel AladdinRGB[6] = {
  {"INT","%", 0, 100, WHITE},
  {"CCT","K", 0, 100, WHITE},
  {"CF","%", 0, 100, WHITE},
  {"RED","%", 0, 100, RED},
  {"GREEN","%", 0, 100, GREEN},
  {"BLUE","%", 0, 100, BLUE}
};

class Profile {
  public:
  std::vector<Channel> channels;
  int dmxChannels;
  int sliderChannels;
  
  Profile(Channel* input, int count, int dmxChannelsA){
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
      channels.push_back(*input);
      input++;
    }
    dmxChannels = dmxChannelsA;
    sliderChannels = count;
  }
};

Profile AladdinBiColor_fixture(AladdinBiColor, 2,2);
Profile AladdinRGB_fixture(AladdinRGB, 6, 5);

Profile *lightProfiles[1][3] = { //index 1 = brand, index 2 = light
  {&AladdinRGB_fixture, &AladdinBiColor_fixture, &AladdinRGB_fixture}
};
```

This way - in my main file - i can access the `Profile objects` with index numbers:

```cpp
void setup(){
  // first parameter of lightProfiles is the brand, second the light of it
  Serial.println(lightProfiles[0][1]->channel[0].maxValue);

}
```

Comment: I think you still want `Channel AladdinBiColor[2];` and the other array as globlas to have access to them in other functions. But yes, the order of initializing the array members and then copying them was the issue